# How to include mailchimp plugin with wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, mailchimp

I’m working on WordPress theme, and this theme has email subscription widget. So I want to include MailChimp plugin to the theme. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro you can't use mailchimp plugin in you theme as a embedded plugin. But you can use TGM plugin activation file to include plugin to your theme. Download a copy of TGM class file from here [TGM plugin activation class](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation/develop/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php) and just copy the `class-tgm-plugin-activation.php` file to your theme directory and add below codes to your theme's `functions.php` file ..

```
<?php

require get_template_directory() . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php'; //add your file path where you put the file

add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'something_register_required_plugins' );

function something_register_required_plugins() {

    $plugins = array(

        array(
            'name'      => 'Mailchimp',
            'slug'      => 'mailchimp',
            'required'  => true,
        ),

    );

    $config = array(
        'id'           => 'something',             // Unique ID for hashing notices for multiple instances of TGMPA.
        'default_path' => '',                      // Default absolute path to bundled plugins.
        'menu'         => 'tgmpa-install-plugins', // Menu slug.
        'parent_slug'  => 'themes.php',            // Parent menu slug.
        'capability'   => 'edit_theme_options',    // Capability needed to view plugin install page, should be a capability associated with the parent menu used.
        'has_notices'  => true,                    // Show admin notices or not.
        'dismissable'  => true,                    // If false, a user cannot dismiss the nag message.
        'dismiss_msg'  => '',                      // If 'dismissable' is false, this message will be output at top of nag.
        'is_automatic' => false,                   // Automatically activate plugins after installation or not.
        'message'      => '',                      // Message to output right before the plugins table.
    );

    tgmpa( $plugins, $config );
}
 ?>
```

This will create a suggestion to your users to install mailchimp plugin from the wordpress.org repository